# Distributional derivative of $\delta*1$ acting on functions not compactly supported

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Distributional derivative of $\delta'*1$ is equal to $(\delta*1)'=1'=0$ when it acts on any $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. However, what happens if $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ does not have a compact support?

In particular, when proving the non-associativity of convolution of distributions
$$(H*\delta')*1=\delta*1=1\ne0=H*0=H*(\delta'*1)$$ where $H$ is the Heaviside function whose distributional derivative is the delta function, we have used the property $\delta'*1=0$ in distribution. However, if we consider how $H*(\delta'*1)$ acts on $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. It is equivalent to $\delta'*1$ acting on the convolution of $f(x)$ with $H(-x)$. This convolution as a function no longer has bounded support. How do we define the action of $\delta'*1$ on it?

Comment: After a quick look I concluded that $\delta'*1$ works for any differentiable test function that has finite integral and vanishes at infinity (having limit zero). And, $\langle \delta'*1,\varphi\rangle=0$ for all such $\varphi.$

Comment: @md2perpe I agree with you on that. But my understanding is that, since $\langle H*(\delta'*1),\phi\rangle=\langle\delta'*1,\tilde{H}*\phi\rangle$ where $\tilde{H}(x)=H(-x)$, the function $\tilde{H}*\phi$ does not vanish at $-\infty$ (it is equal to $\int_{x}^\infty f(s)ds$)

Comment: Isn't the reason associativity fails that the convolution isn't even defined?

Comment: @md2perpe On this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics) this non-associativity is used as an example, so I am assuming that there is a way to define convolution with non-compact distributions like $H$, but then I get stuck in verifying the right-hand side because I cannot figure out what it actually means by $H*(\delta'*1)$.

Comment: I don't think that the editor means that those convolutions are defined. He might not even have realized that they are not. I think that he only wants to show that one cannot do calculations naively.

Comment: @md2perpe I guess you're right. Thanks for the help.